# Facing issue with mysql database with node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-connection, unhandled-exception

i have created express app with mysql database.
when i call mysql query it works fine and then i call my view. loading view take few minute(2-3 min) and app crashed with bellow error.

events.js:287
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
at Connection._handleProtocolError (C:\Users\AMW\Desktop\dishmize\dishmize\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:423:8)
at Protocol.emit (events.js:310:20)
at Protocol.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
at Protocol._delegateError (C:\Users\AMW\Desktop\dishmize\dishmize\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:398:10)
at Protocol.handleNetworkError (C:\Users\AMW\Desktop\dishmize\dishmize\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:371:10)
at Connection._handleNetworkError (C:\Users\AMW\Desktop\dishmize\dishmize\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:418:18)
at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3) {
errno: 'ECONNRESET',
code: 'ECONNRESET',
syscall: 'read',
fatal: true
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

i already spend 8- 10 hours.
please help me to resolve this issue.
thanks

#### Update:

```
const options = { 
    user: config.get('MYSQL_USER'), 
    password: config.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD'), 
    database:config.get('DATABASE'), 
    host: config.get('HOST'), 
    port: 3306 
} 

const connection = mysql.createConnection(options); 
connection.connect( function (err) { 
    if (err) { 
        console.log("!!! Cannot connect !!! Error:"); throw err; 
    } else { 
        console.log("Connection established."); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: create a connection pool instead of a single connection.

Comment: and please share your MySQL connection code snippet.

Comment: const options =  { user:config.get('MYSQL_USER'),
                             password: config.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
                             database:config.get('DATABASE'),
                             host: config.get('HOST'),
                             port: 3306 
                         } 
const connection = mysql.createConnection(options);

connection.connect(
 function (err) { 
 if (err) { 
  console.log("!!! Cannot connect !!! Error:");
  throw err;
 }
 else
 {
    console.log("Connection established.");
 } 
});

Answer (score 1):

use below

```
const options = { connectionLimit :10, user:config.get('MYSQL_USER'), password: config.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD'), database:config.get('DATABASE'), host: config.get('HOST'), port: 3306 } 
const connection_pool = mysql.createPool(options); 

connection_pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```

provide connectionLimit according to you use this is pool size of connection